# wordpress not able to open theme-editor.php

Tags: themes

I am having a site radhanath-swami.info. I logged as admin using "radhanath-swami.info/wp-admin".

then i tried "radhanath-swami.info/wp-admin/theme-editor.php"

```
  You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.
```

I dont know what to do. I googled a lot  but not much help. I dont have access to the server not the ftp. Whatever i can do is only from admin dashboard.

I was using theme esplanade, due to some reasons i have changed to another theme. THen i have deleted the esplande theme.

Later I have decided to use esplanade, so installed it again and activated it. From then the theme-editor.php is not working. Before this theme-editor.php was working.

I also checked with changing to other theme. It also now shows the same permission thing when i open theme-editor.php

I have also tried removing all the plugins still same message. I feel there are some bugs in the wordpress

Comment: Have you searched Google for "WordPress deactivate Theme editor"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try enable the theme editor via WP-Config as shown here: http://www.wp-edge.com/how-to-enabledisable-wordpress-theme-editor/

It's probably impossible if you don't have FTP access - but its possible that the theme editor was enabled previously via the theme funcitons.php and has since been disabled once you re-installed a fresh version of it.

Comment: thank you very very much. I was desparately looking for the solution

Answer (score 1):

Simply add one line to your `wp-config.php` file:

```
define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', FALSE );
```

This can later (by a theme) be set to `TRUE` as well and therefore disabling the Theme and Plugin editor.

Comment: As far as accepted answer provides dead link only this must be accepted.